# Can I use bool data type as below?in C language

Tags: c, boolean

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include<stdbool.h>  
int main()  
{
    bool x;
    bool y;
    printf("Please enter two numbers, each of which can be 0 or non-0: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    printf("The value of x&&y is %d", x&&y);  
    printf("\nThe value of x||y is %d", x||y);  
    printf("\nThe value of !x is %d", !x);  
    printf("\nThe value of !x is %d", y^x);  
}
```

Why the output is coming like this? (wrongly)

```
Please enter two numbers, each of which can be 0 or non-0: 1 0
The value of x&&y is 0
The value of x||y is 0
The value of !x is 1
The value of !x is 0
```

According to boolean algebra these should be:

```
The value of x&&y is 0 ,
The value of x||y is 1 ,
The value of !x is 1 ,
The value of !x is 1
```

Answer (score 2):

No you cant scanf `bool` values using "%d" format. It expects pointer to `int` parameter. You need to pass pointers to `int` variables then convert it to `bool`.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include<stdbool.h>  
int main()  
{
    bool x;
    bool y;
    int ix,iy;
    printf("Please enter two numbers, each of which can be 0 or non-0: ");
    if(scanf("%d %d", &ix, &iy) == 2)
    {
        x = !!ix; y = !!iy;
        printf("\nThe value of x&&y is %d", x&&y);  
        printf("\nThe value of x||y is %d", x||y);  
        printf("\nThe value of !x is %d", !x);  
        printf("\nThe value of x ^ y is %d", y^x);  
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/53nMjcY8j

In the code above any non-zero integer value will be considered true.

Answer (score 1):

For `%d`, `scanf` expects a pointer to an `int` to be passed. When a pointer to a `bool` is passed instead, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. There is no `scanf` conversion specifier for reading a `bool`.

To read a “0” or “1” character as a `bool`, read the character, handle an error if it is not “0” or “1”, and, if it is a “0” or “1”, set a `bool` value to correspond.